# What other special characters like "\r" can be used to prettify output in Python?

Tags: python, formatting, special-characters

I just learned about '\r' and the ability to update a line of text, like:

```
"40% complete"
```

...

```
"50% complete"
```

over time inline.

So excited. Are there any other ways to move a cursor around an output (specifically that would work for Python 3 on Windows)? What if my dynamic status spans multiple lines, like:

```
==========STATUS============
Task 1..........40% complete
Task 2...........7% complete
Task 3.........100% complete
============================
```

(Where % complete changes on each task independently of the others.)

Is there a special character like \r that moves up or down a line, or moves the cursor left or right?

(Sorry if there's a guide to this, searching "\r" is not very helpful, and lists of special characters I found didn't quite include what I was looking for.)

Thanks for any help!

Refs:

GNU special characters: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Special-characters.html#Special%20characters

Pretty python output (linux only?): http://www.darkcoding.net/software/pretty-command-line-console-output-on-unix-in-python-and-go-lang/

Comment: Searching for `\r` is indeed very hard. What you want to search for is `carriage return`. However, I don't think that'll help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you need to set terminal mode before using special characters.
Lately I saw a crossplatform module to colorize output.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

There are special chars to move the cursor.

Also you may use ncurces to make text GUI.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you console supports ANSI escape sequences you can use those.

Try this on your console:

```
print ('\x1b[31;1mThis is red')
```

If it shows the text in bold red, your console supports CSI and you can do many tricks to your cursor.

Cf [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Sadly no dice on the console support, but that is a really cool list of CSI codes!